Update password-auth Using Ansible
I would like to update /etc/pam.d/password-auth using Ansible to have the following line (or a similar one with the remember=5 argument added)
password requisite pam_pwhistory.so remember=5

If a similar line already exists with, say, different arguments, I know the following ansible code will add/update the remember argument
    - name: "Prohibit password reuse for a minimum of five generations"
      community.general.pamd:
        name: password-auth
        type: password
        control: requisite
        module_path: pam_pwhistory.so
        module_arguments: "remember=5"
        state: args_present

However, if there isn't already a password requisite pam_pwhistory.so rule the above Ansible does nothing. In order to add the rule I need to do the following:
    - name: "Prohibit password reuse for a minimum of five generations"
      community.general.pamd:
        name: password-auth
        type: password
        control: requisite
        module_path: pam_pwquality.so
        new_type: password
        new_control: requisite
        new_module_path: pam_pwhistory.so
        state: after
        module_arguments: "remember=5"

Which will add the line if it doesn't exist but will not update the line if the argument is missing or incorrect.
I can do this in two passes. First create the line if missing and then update the line if needed.
Is there any way I can do this in a single pass?
